# aws - how to get one lambda to call another

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The 2nd lambda works and inserts a record into dynamoDB when I test it alone.

I then have another lambda which is trying to call it but nothing seems to happen.

Cloudwatch logs show no issues and show puts statements after call.
But dynamodb table doesn't get any records inserted.

Both lambdas have full lambda acccess

### Lambda 2 - LamdaLamdaDynamodb

2nd lambda that works on its own:

```
# lambda 'two'
require 'aws-sdk-lambda'
require 'aws-sdk-dynamodb'
require 'time'
require 'json'

def handler(event:, context:)
  p "index2"
  dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'us-east-2')
  item = {
      "name": "#{Time.now.to_s[0..19]} #{event['Records'][0]['eventSource']} #{event['Records'][0]['eventName']}",
      "eventTime": "#{Time.now.to_s[0..19]}",
      "eventSource": "lambda",
      "description": "from lambda event",
      "eventID": "#{event['Records'][0]['eventID']}",
      "eventName": "#{event['Records'][0]['eventName']}", 
      "eventSource":"#{event['Records'][0]['eventSource']}",
      "awsRegion":"#{event['Records'][0]['awsRegion']}"
  }
  params = {
      table_name: 'any_event',
      item: item
  }
  begin
    dynamodb.put_item(params)
    puts 'Added item'
  rescue  Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ServiceError => error
    puts 'Unable to add item:'
    puts error.message
  end
end
```

### Lambda 1 - triggerLamdaLamda

First Lambda that is trying to call it:

```
require 'aws-sdk-lambda'
require 'time'
require 'json'
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  client = Aws::Lambda::Client.new(region: 'us-east-2')
  payload = '{"name": "thing"}' 
  the_payload = JSON.generate(payload)
  resp = client.invoke({
    function_name: 'LamdaLamdaDynamodb',
    invocation_type: 'RequestResponse',
    log_type: 'None',
    payload: the_payload
  })
end
```

Comment: The correct way would be to use SNS

Comment: Maybe you are updating an existing record and not inserting a new record

Comment: Good thought.  However I use time as key to avoid that. and it continues to not post over several attempts to trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using time as a key is not a good idea. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-load.html
2. You can use Step Functions to chain Lambda functions in a workflow fashion.
3. The first lambda can emit a CloudWatch event that the second Lambda can listen for as a trigger. The event would contain the payload.

IMO: [3] is the easiest way to do this. You can also try setting the function_name parameter to the ARN of the Lambda function.

Comment: +1 for the time comment.  I was just playing but I should still practice good techniques for myself and others.  I added a `.reverse` to help. for small to medium this should be ok

Answer (score 2):

- You can call a lambda form another lambda. [github python & terraform implementation](https://github.com/amittn/lambda-invoking-lambda)
- The calling lambda should have a role with attached policy having `lambda:InvokeFunction` action.
- The calling lambda assuming its calling the other 2 lambda synchronously should have `invocationType=RequestResponse`(its the default type).[AWSJavaScriptSDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property)

```
invoke_resp = LAMBDA_CLIENT.invoke(
        FunctionName='second_lambda',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=encoded_payload)
```

- Different `invocationType` are as follows `RequestResponse (default)`, `Event` and `DryRun`.[aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) Depending upon your synchronous invocation or  asynchronous invocation.
- In your case the only thing missing which i can think of is, This operation requires permission for the **lambda:InvokeFunction** action.